# how to count cycles?

Tags: c, performance, assembly

I'm trying to find the find the relative merits of 2 small functions in C. One that adds by loop, one that adds by explicit variables. The functions are irrelevant themselves, but I'd like someone to teach me how to count cycles so as to compare the algorithms. So f1 will take 10 cycles, while f2 will take 8. That's the kind of reasoning I would like to do. No performance measurements (e.g. `gprof` experiments) at this point, just good old instruction counting.

Is there a good way to do this? Are there tools? Documentation? I'm writing C, compiling with `gcc` on an x86 architecture.

Comment: Do you want to count instructions or cycles? These are two different things.

Comment: Is this exercise purely exploratory? Or are you actually concerned with it. If it's the former, cool. If it's the latter, I'm a little worried that your focus is in the wrong spot. :-p

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the clarification question: I want cycles, so I can compare performance.

Comment: Exploratory. Purely theoretical question for a paper I'm writing, that's all.

Comment: @Dervin:  Clicks is not the term you are after.  Cycles is what you are after. Clicks are what you do with a mouse ;)

Comment: Why no measurements? If the correct answer is predictable, then measuring will give you a consistent answer that's correct at least for your particular hardware. If the correct answer is that it's inherently unpredictable (e.g. because your code accesses memory, and cache contents aren't deterministic on most real-live systems) then good old instruction counting won't tell you the cycle count either.

Comment: No, you can't do that anymore. It used to be (a long time ago) that each assembly instruction executed in a fixed number of clocks, and you could add them up to figure out how fast a piece of code would execute. Loved that. :-).  Nowadays, with out of order execution, multi instruction issue per clock, and multi-level caches, you just cannot figure out execution speed from looking at the instructions. You **have** to measure. Sorry!

Comment: @Bo Persson You should put that as an answer so you can earn rep. That's easily the best answer given here so far.

Comment: @glowcoder: what a relief that it was exploratory so you didn't have to worry about his focus being in the wrong spot.

Comment: @Olof As should be clear by reading the other comments, simply counting instructions is a fairly poor way to benchmark your code. Your statement, in its sarcasm, implies that we shouldn't be concerned about what why other people are asking the questions they are. I feel this is quite contrary to the nature of this community.

Comment: @glowcoder: the man asked a perfectly valid question. I find it disturbing that his reasons for asking it are questioned. Granted, if he had asked if anyone knows how to hack into government systems that would certainly have been reason for concern. As for measuring clock cycles many of the things we take for granted when developing software originated from people counting (of course among many other things) clock cycles to "find the relative merits" as DT so aptly puts it. Whether he counts clock cycles or instructions is none of our business - our business is to help, if we can.

Comment: @Olof the question is only valid in the proper context. He would be far better off asking the question "Is counting cycles going to achieve my goal?" first. And that's what we do here at SO - we answer the meta questions first because doing things smartly is just as important as doing them right. Doing something right for the wrong reason is *wrong*, and we don't let fellow developers fall into those traps if we can help it. "Our business is to help, if we can" - you're absolutely right. Helping folks do the right thing is better than helping them do what they think they want.

Comment: @glowcoder: with all respect, who are we to say what is right or what is wrong? What is better? Anyone who attempts to work things out for himself will run into walls and they will send him off in new directions, it's perfectly normal when learning. How can we be sure that we're not deflecting him from some path with a goal that we know nothing of? He says "I'd like someone to teach me how to count cycles so as to compare the algorithms" (maybe he edited his question). To me helping means telling him what I know and describing pitfalls I've experienced. What he does with it is up to him.

Comment: @Olof you're making my point for me! One of those pitfalls is "This is an inaccurate form of benchmarking."

Comment: @glowcoder: to begin with, that is an incorrect statement if you mean using clock cycles. All methods have pros and cons. There are nuances to using clock cycles such as the shorter the code sequence the more important it is to adjust for measurement overhead and vice versa. That if you want to convert to elapsed time you need to turn off CPU throttling. That's a far cry from flatly stating that it "is an inaccurate form of benchmarking." Besides, I reacted to your worrying about his "focus" and passing judgement "if it's the former, cool" which to me is way out of line.

Comment: @Olof if you read the above comments, other users clearly illustrate why they feel counting instructors *or* cycles is a poor decision. In any case, it's obvious you and I feel differently about the issue. If you feel my comments were out of line, feel free to flag them as inappropriate and a moderator will make a decision. Otherwise, I'm going to spend my time here helping people, and not carrying on this conversation. *cheers*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/

> PAPI_get_real_cyc(3) - return the total number of cycles since some arbitrary starting point

Answer (score 5):

Assembler instruction `rdtsc` (Read Time-Stamp Counter) retun in EDX:EAX registers the current CPU ticks count, started at CPU reset. If your CPU runing at 3GHz then one tick is 1/3GHz.

EDIT:
Under MS windows the API call `QueryPerformanceFrequency` return the number of ticks per second.

Comment: @GJ: its not quite that simple.  Modern processors scale their speed depending on load so that you never know how fast the cpu is clocked at any given moment. It DOES give the cycles though.

Comment: @Goz: Agree, but the tick (clock) count should be the same.

Comment: @BlackBear: Amm.. 1/Hz = s.  So 1/3GHz = 1/3G s

Comment: @Blackbear:  Not true.  If the processor has underclocked itself to 1Ghz ... then 1 cycle takes 3 times as long.  Bring intel's i7 turbo boost into it and you have even more issues ...

Comment: @Goz: you didn't get it. @GJ did :)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately timing the code is as error prone as visually counting instructions and clock cycles.  Be it a debugger or other tool or re-compiling the code with a re-run 10000000 times and time it kind of thing, you change where things land in the cache line, the frequency of the cache hits and misses, etc.  You can mitigate some of this by adding or removing some code upstream from the module of code being tested, (to cause a few instructions added and removed changing the alignment of your program and sometimes of your data).

With experience you can develop an eye for performance by looking at the disassembly (as well as the high level code).  There is no substitute for timing the code, problem is timing the code is error prone.  The experience comes from many experiements and trying to fully understand why adding or removing one instruction made no or dramatic differences.  Why code added or removed in a completely different unrelated area of the module under test made huge performance differences on the module under test.

Comment: Also understand that the processor is no longer the bottleneck to performance it often sits around waiting on memory and other I/O

Answer (score 2):

As GJ has written in another answer I also recommend using the "rdtsc" instruction (rather than calling some operating system function which looks right).

I've written quite a few answers on this topic. Rdtsc allows you to calculate the elapsed clock cycles in the code's "natural" execution environment rather than having to resort to calling it ten million times which may not be feasible as not all functions are black boxes.

If you want to calculate elapsed time you might want to shut off energy-saving on the CPUs. If it's only a matter of clock cycles this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compare the performance, the easiest way is to put your algorithm in a loop and run it 1000 or 1000000 times.

Once you are running it enough times that the small differences can be seen, run `time ./my_program` which will give you the amount of processor time that it used.

Do this a few times to get a sampling and compare the results.

Trying to count instructions won't help you on x86 architecture.  This is because different instructions can take significantly different amounts of time to execute.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using simulators. Take a look at PTLsim it will give you the number of cycles, other than that maybe you would like to take a look at some tools to count the number of times each assembly line is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gcc -S your_program.c`. `-S` tells gcc to generate the assembly listing, that will be named `your_program.s`.

Comment: right, that's what I do: and then? Counting clicks by hand like this would be tedious, to say the least.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was mistaken about where your problem lies. I once used the Simics tool (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simics) to count cycles. This is a commercial product, be if you're at a university you may get an academic licence for free. Simics provides cycle-precise processor simulation, and is able to gather statistics.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of high performance clocks around.  QueryPerformanceCounter is microsofts.  The general trick is to run the function 10s of thousands of time and time how long it takes.  Then divide the time taken by the number of loops.  You'll find that each loop takes a slightly different length of time so this testing over multiple passes is the only way to truly find out how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a trivial question. Let me try to explain:

There are several tools on different OS to do exactly what you want, but those tools are usually part of a bigger environment. Every instruction is translated into a certain number of cycles, depending on the CPU the compiler ran on, and the CPU the program was executed.

I can't give you a definitive answer, because I do not have enough data to pass my judgement on, but I work for IBM in the database area and we use tools to measure cycles and instructures for our code and those traces are only valid for the actual CPU the program was compiled and was running on.
Depending on the internal structure of your CPU's piplining and on the effeciency of your  compiler, the resulting code will most likely still have cache misses and other areas you have to worry about. (In that case you may want to look into FDPR...)

If you want to know how many cycles your program needs to run on your CPU (which was compiled with your compiler), you have to understand how the CPU works and how the compiler generarated the code.

I'm sorry, if the answer was not sufficient enough to solve your problem at hand. You said you are using gcc on an x86 arch. I would work with getting the assembly code mapped to your CPU.
I'm sure you will find some areas, where gcc could have done a better job...